# Reload a keyboard listener on a frame after change of src

Tags: javascript, html, dom, frames

I'm trying to make a small bookmarklet that allows the user to navigate through some webcomics or series of articles using 'j' and 'k'. I based my code on existing bookmarklets to go to the 'next' page or to the 'previous'.

```
(function() {
    var newWindow = window.open('about:blank', '_blank');
    newWindow.document.write('<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd"><html><head><title>' +
        document.title + '</title></head><frameset><frame src="' + location.href + '"></frameset></html>');
    newWindow.document.close();
    newWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('frame')[0].contentDocument.onkeypress = function(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        var charCode = (typeof e.which == 'number') ? e.which : e.keyCode;
        if (charCode) {
            alert(charCode);
            var frame = newWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('frame')[0];
            var document = frame.contentDocument
            if (String.fromCharCode(charCode) == 'j') {
                z = document.getElementsByTagName('link');
                for (i = 0; a = z[i++];) {
                    if (a.rel == 'previous') {
                        frame.src = a.href;
                        return;
                    }
                }
                m = frame.src.match(/^(.+\D)(\d+)(\D*)/);
                if (m) {
                    s = '' + (1 * m[2] - 1);
                    while (s.length < m[2].length) s = '0' + s;
                    frame.src = m[1] + s + m[3];
                }
            } else if (String.fromCharCode(charCode) == 'k') {
                z = document.getElementsByTagName('link');
                for (i = 0; a = z[i++];) {
                    if (a.rel == 'next') {
                        frame.src = a.href;
                        return;
                    }
                }
                m = frame.src.match(/^(.+\D)(\d+)(\D*)/);
                if (m) {
                    s = '' + (1 * m[2] + 1);
                    while (s.length < m[2].length) s = '0' + s;
                    frame.src = m[1] + s + m[3];
                }
            }
        }
    }

})()
```

For the moment, I am trying to open a new window and use a frame.
The onkeypress function is **not** assigned but I think it is just because the page is not loaded when it tries to, because when I wait a bit and try to assign it from the JS console of the first page, it works. I think that waiting for the load to be complete will be sufficient (I will try and add it, I am just a beginner in JS).

The problem is that when the src of the frame changes, the onkeypress function is lost. How can I fix that?

I think I should use some listener on the window, but how?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it !

```
(function() {
    window.document.write('<html><frameset><frame src=""></frameset></html>');
    window.document.close();
    var frame = window.document.getElementsByTagName('frame')[0];
    window.document.onkeypress = function(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        var charCode = (typeof e.which == 'number') ? e.which : e.keyCode;
        if (charCode) {
            var document = frame.contentDocument
            if (String.fromCharCode(charCode) == 'j') {
                z = document.getElementsByTagName('link');
                for (i = 0; a = z[i++];) {
                    if (a.rel == 'previous') {
                        frame.src = a.href;
                        return;
                    }
                }
                m = frame.src.match(/^(.+\D)(\d+)(\D*)/);
                if (m) {
                    s = '' + (1 * m[2] - 1);
                    while (s.length < m[2].length) s = '0' + s;
                    frame.src = m[1] + s + m[3];
                }
            } else if (String.fromCharCode(charCode) == 'k') {
                z = document.getElementsByTagName('link');
                for (i = 0; a = z[i++];) {
                    if (a.rel == 'next') {
                        frame.src = a.href;
                        return;
                    }
                }
                m = frame.src.match(/^(.+\D)(\d+)(\D*)/);
                if (m) {
                    s = '' + (1 * m[2] + 1);
                    while (s.length < m[2].length) s = '0' + s;
                    frame.src = m[1] + s + m[3];
                }
            }
        }
    };
    frame.addEventListener("load", function() {
        frame.contentDocument.onkeypress = window.document.onkeypress;
        window.history.pushState({}, "", frame.src);
        document.title = frame.contentDocument.title
    })
    frame.src = location.href;
})();
```